# android studio java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android, firebase

> I keep getting this ConcurrentModificationException from Firebase

```
  Process: com.example.myclass, PID: 9145
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at com.example.myclass.Fragments.ChatFragment$2.onDataChange(ChatFragment.java:109)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

> I already changed the code multiple times (such as using "addAll" outside of the loop etc.) but I still get the bug. Now I'm out of ideas what I could change to fix this.
>   Here is my current code:

```
    private void readChat(){
    mUsers = new ArrayList<>();

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mUsers.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                //display 1 users from chat
                for (String id : userlist){
                    if (user.getId().equals(id)){
                        if (mUsers.size()!=0){        
                            for (User user1 : mUsers){ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<THIS ERRORR
                                if(!user.equals(user1.getId())){
                                    mUsers.add(user);

                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            mUsers.add(user);

                               }
                    }
                }

            }

            userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(),mUsers);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "database error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

> The only line I can imagine that might cause a problem would be:

```
                                for (User user1 : mUsers){
                                if(!user.equals(user1.getId())){
                                    mUsers.add(user);

                                }
                            }
```

> And the more extended code snippet:

public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

private UserAdapter userAdapter;
private List<User>mUsers;

private FirebaseUser fuser;
private DatabaseReference reference;

private List<String>userlist;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat,container,false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    userlist = new ArrayList<>();

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userlist.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);

                if(chat.getSender().equals(fuser.getUid())){
                    userlist.add(chat.getReceiver());

                }
                if (chat.getReceiver().equals(fuser.getUid())){
                    userlist.add(chat.getSender());
                }
            }

            readChat();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



    return view;




}

private void readChat(){
    mUsers = new ArrayList<>();

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mUsers.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                //display 1 users from chat
                for (String id : userlist){
                    if (user.getId().equals(id)){
                        if (mUsers.size()!=0){
                            for (User user1 : mUsers){
                                if(!user.equals(user1.getId())){
                                    mUsers.add(user);

                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            mUsers.add(user);

                               }
                    }
                }

            }

            userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(),mUsers);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "database error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As per OracleDocs for [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behaviour at an undetermined time
>   in the future.

To resolve this issue, I followed this [ConcurrentModificationException](https://www.journaldev.com/378/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception) and it has very good explanation of resolving such exception.

How we can avoid:

1. If you are using JDK1.5 or higher then you can use ConcurrentHashMap
   and CopyOnWriteArrayList classes. This is the recommended approach
   to avoid concurrent modification exception. **(I followed this approach)**
2. To Avoid ConcurrentModificationException in multi-threaded
   environment You can convert the list to an array and then iterate on
   the array. This approach works well for small or medium size list
   but if the list is large then it will affect the performance a lot.
3. You can lock the list while iterating by putting it in a
   synchronised block. This approach is not recommended because it will
   cease the benefits of multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you got the problem point - to Avoid ConcurrentModificationException -

You can use the iterator to remove/add the object from underlying collection object. But in this case, you can remove the same object and not any other object from the list.

```
    Iterator<String> iterator = mUsers.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String value = iterator.next();
        mUsers.add("user1");
        mUsers.add("user2");
    }
```

Hope this will help you.